# 3D model does not show up in AR

Tags: swift, arkit

I'm using the PlacingObjects ARKit example and i'm trying to add my own object to it. My object is replacing the candle. When I launch the app on my phone and try to produce the object, I click it and nothing happens. All the other objects work fine. Here is the swift file for my object.

```
  import Foundation
  import SceneKit

  class Turret: VirtualObject {

      override init() {
          super.init(modelName: "Turret", fileExtension: "scn",  thumbImageFilename: "candle", title: "Turret")
      }

      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
      }

   }
```

The thumb image remains candle because it would crash if I opened the menu, probably because its trying to open a thumbnail that doesn't exist.
I've been looking in all of the files to try and find out why, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: There's far too little to go on here. (And really, your question is more about how to extend that particular code sample than anything specific to ARKit/ScneKit in general.) There's a specific folder/file structure in that project for each of the models it uses—did you replicate that for your "Turret.scn"? Is your turret model sized to fit in AR? (Check the bounding box in the SceneKit editor; if it's more than a few meters in size, placing it on the table in front of you might put you "inside" the object.)

Comment: The code you have looks correct. Have you made sure to include your 3D models in the project in SCN format?